# Delphi Multi Styles for Multiplatforms

Tags: android, delphi

I create form and attached two **TStylebook** on it.

The first one have Windows Style (*MetropolisUIBlack.vsf*) the second one have Android style (*AndroidLight.fsf*)

On Form create i wrote the following code

```
procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {$IFDEF  MSWINDOWS}
    Self.StyleBook := WinStyle;
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF  ANDROID}
    Self.StyleBook := DroidStyle;
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

The problem is if the Android style was selected at design time and i run the application on Windows i get the following message

> The style you have chosen is not available for your currently selected
>   target platform. You can select a custom style or remove the stylebook
>   to allow FireMonkey to automatically load the native style at run time

---

How i can set the Stylebook depending on the platform regardless what i have select on the form design ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify default platform specific style for each platform in same StyleBook?

You do this by double clicking on a StyleBook icon which opens the StyleBook Editor.

Then in the Style Editor you click on the `PLUS` button near the `Platform` dropdown list to add desired platforms.

After that simply switch to desired platform and chose which style you want to use for it.

Comment: From what I know in latest versions of Delphi StyleBook is designed in a way so that it automatically detects which platform it is being run on and then choses appropriate style. You don't need to do this by code.